# How can I find the x and y coordinates from a point in space?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let's say that we have a point in space (x,y,z)

Here are the values that would be known:

```
The radius r
The length of line a
The angle Theta
```

We should also assume that the value for z will **ALWAYS** be positive.

**With those three values, how do we find x and y?**

Here are a couple of images to make the problem clearer

[image]

Pay no attention to the value 45 - it is only in the image to illustrate that the value will be some number in degrees radius.

[image]

Comment: A "radius" is not an angle, is a lenght, so it doesn't make sense for it to be $45$ degrees.

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong understandind of the term radius. In your case $a$ is the radius. In your case $r$ is called the polar angle.

Anyway. You get
$$ x(a,r,t) = a\cos(r)\cos(t) $$
$$ y(a,r,t) = a\sin(r)\cos(t) $$
$$ z(a,r,t) = a\sin(t) $$

Comment: Well ... the last trig class I had was in 1992 ... and I haven't used it since ... so in that context ... I think I'm doing alright.  :-)

Comment: It’s okay, I’m not criticising you, I’m just pointing it out, so that you know.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond and help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Position of a point in space can be represented by a vector which has length L:

$L=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

and makes angles $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ with axis x, y and z respectively. The                                                                                         value of these angles can be found using following formulas:

$\ cos (\alpha)=\frac xL$

$\cos (\beta)=\frac yL$

$\cos (\gamma)=\frac zL$

If you want to find angle between line L with Plane XZ for example , you have to find the lengh of projection of L on plane XZ :

$L'=\sqrt {(L \cos \alpha)^2+L\cos \gamma)^2}=L \sqrt{\cos^2 \alpha +\cos^2 \gamma}$

And angle between L and its projection L' is ($\theta$) which can be found as:

$\cos \theta= \frac {L'}L=\sqrt{ \cos^2 \alpha+\cos^2\gamma}$

Comment: Which locations inside the right triangle are alpha, beta and lamda? Which one is the right angle and which one is opposite of the right angle?